# is ros compatible with parrot's mini drones like rolling spider and jumping sumo?

Tags: ros, parrot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i was thinking of working on parrot's mini drones like jumping sumo or rolling spider. so i wanted to know if they could be operated using ros?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214244/is-ros-compatible-with-parrot%27s-mini-drones-like-rolling-spider-and-jumping-sumo?/) by [sg_774](https://answers.ros.org/users/23284/sg_774/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2015-11-25**:
I'm also interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- For Rolling Spider, there are quite a few wrappers of the Parrot SDK available on Github : https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=rolling+spider&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults . There might be some compatible with ROS.
- For th Jumping Sumo, I've been working on a prototype. The source code is available there : https://github.com/arnaud-ramey/rossumo . It is a work in progress and to be documented, but supports the video stream, the control (motion), and the animations.

Cheers !

---

Originally posted by [anonymous2054](https://answers.ros.org/users/2054/anonymous2054/) with karma: 101 on 2016-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [edoca](https://answers.ros.org/users/27637/edoca/) on 2016-07-29**:
Hi Arnaud ! I was wondering whether you had tested the use of rossumo on a jumping race drone, and if not, if you think that it would be compatible. Indeed, I was thinking of using it to test a few algorithms dedicated to obstacle perception. Cheers !

**Comment by [anonymous2054](https://answers.ros.org/users/2054/anonymous2054/) on 2016-07-29**:
Hi Edoca,
Excellent question.
I don't own a Jumping Race so cannot really tell.

But two things make me confident about that:

1. the Jumping Race is the same as the Sumo, except for an increased speed and the ability to access that speed from the SDK ;

**Comment by [anonymous2054](https://answers.ros.org/users/2054/anonymous2054/) on 2016-07-29**:
2) the Parrot SDK is supposed to be common for all minidrones.

So I encourage you to test it and share your conclusions :)
I am available for debugging / help - fill issues on the Github page.
Cheers!

**Comment by [sg_774](https://answers.ros.org/users/23284/sg_774/) on 2016-10-23**:
Hi Arnaud ! I was wondering if your ROS package could be used along with microsoft Kinect? Was thinking of using it for gesture control of jumping sumo using ROS and kinect.

**Comment by [anonymous2054](https://answers.ros.org/users/2054/anonymous2054/) on 2016-10-24**:
Hello, there shouldn't be any trouble using this package alongside with a kinect one, for instance openNi. As long as you comply with the topics names and types, it should work out of the box. Keep me updated in case of trouble.